# Concatenate and display a string variable and a symbol in a Text view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to concatenate and display a `string variable` and a symbol in a `Text` view in SwiftUI, I basically need the effect you get when using string interpolation as follows...

```
Text("Some Text \(Image(systemName: "star"))")
```

[image]

I basically need to display text and a symbol but the text comes from a variable, something like the following which gives me an error...

```
    let someText = "Some Text"
    let someTextPlusImage = someText + Text(Image(systemName: "star")

    Text(someTextPlusImage)
```

Error:

> error: Segmentation fault: 11

How can I concatenate and display a `string variable` and a symbol in a `Text` view in SwiftUI?

Comment: Have you heard of an `HStack`?

Comment: A `String` isn't a `View`  You can `+` a `String` with a `String` and a `Text` with a `Text` but not a `String` with a `Text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert like this

```
Text("\(someText) \(Image(systemName: "star"))")
```

Comment: God, I tried `"\(someText) \(Image(systemName: "star"))"` but didn't work, I never tried `Text("\(someText) \(Image(systemName: "star"))")`. I did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Next variant also works (for example if needed in `ForEach`, etc.)

```
Text(someText) + Text(Image(systemName: "star"))
```